# Do you put capital letters to the first letter of a quotation if it is in the middle of a sentace?

Tags: grammar

For a statistics assignment, I am writing an essay on the difference in marathon performance between older and younger athletes. One of my sentences is this:

> Richard Askwith argued that the experience which comes with age can make older athletes still competitive, stating that “your perception of time changes with age. You become more patient in training and in racing … rather than fretting about the distance, we just cruise along in a more relaxed frame of mind”.

Should the first letter of the quotation (your) be capitalized?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to show it as direct narration, you should start in upper case, //.....still competitive, stating, “Your perception of time changes with age. You become more patient in training and in racing … rather than fretting about the distance, we just cruise along in a more relaxed frame of mind”. In that case, do not use 'that' before it, instead put a comma.

Comment: Some editors will put the first letter in square brackets to indicate that it was capitalised differently in the source material: *...stating that "[y]our perception of time..."*. This isn't universal, though.

Comment: @jsheeran The source material being the spoken word, capitalisation was not in issue.

Comment: I'd avoid 'stating that' as a quotative verb; 'stating' works.

Answer (score 1):

This is mainly a question of style. I suggest that if the first word of the quote is not the first word of the sentence, then you preface the quote with an ellipsis marking:

*"**...** your perception of time changes with age.*